# What is the power set of a set containing an empty set and the set of empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basically what is the power set of $ \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset\}\} $?

Answer (score 3):

Denote $A=\emptyset$, $B=\{\emptyset\}$, $X=\{A, B\}$

We have $P(X)=\{\emptyset, \{A\},\{B\},\{A,B\}\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} \}$

Comment: @Chappers, I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you, that looks much nicer :)